# User comments on a post

Tags: php, android, ios, api, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2 to make a rest API to mobile apps. In my application users can create posts where other users can comment on, which means a post has many comments and each comment should identify which user has posted the comment.

Below I have drawn an ER-diagram. As you can see a post has many comments, but how can I implement which comments belongs to which user? Another thing is when a user comments on a post how will that user get notified when another comment is added to the post?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make a foreign key in comments table linking to the users table so that you know which comment belongs to which user.

When some one comments on any post then you can get all the comments for that post using the post_id field in your comments table. Now from all these comments you can get their respective users through the foreign key which you made above. Now these are all the users who had commented on the same post which just received the new comment. Now you can notify all these users that a new comment has been made on the post, they had commented on before.